# upload files with strange chars when names have accents

Tags: php, file-upload, utf-8, upload

Im was with some problem with strange chars when I do inserts on my database and I solve it searching for solutions in stackoverflow with: `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8".`

But, Im also having some problems, when I upload files, for example, If I upload a file with name "1º class", it is saved on my computer with name: "1Âº class", I also have problems when I use accents on my uploaded files. But I dont understand why this is happening and none solution for this.

Do you know how we can solve this situations?

Answer (score 1):

Check the content-type of your page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

make sure the page itself is coded in uft-8 (eg. with Notepad++)

Comment: Thanks for your answer user3132781, but I already Have that meta in my project... and dont works!

Answer (score 0):

You should set `default_charset` in your php.ini. It should be set with UTF-8. Check your settings with `phpinfo()` and search for `default_charset`.